# What are bond lengths and angles for picric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

I am working on a project in which I am required to create a model of [picric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picric_acid). I do not understand how to find the bond lengths, bond angles, shape, and atom size of this molecule. Any help in finding these measurements or in showing me how to find them would be amazing!

Comment: Homework? You should be able to find out something, if only via google. Report that, and ask what stays unclear.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to take a crystal structure available for free from [Crystallography Open Database](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/index.php), [COD#5000146](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/5000146.html). The entry webpage already has a JSmol script loaded, so you should see the molecular structure loaded on a black area. Selecting `RMB (right mouse button) -> Measurements -> Show Measurements` allows you to measure linear and angular parameters with mouse clicks.

Alternatively, you can download the CIF-file ([5000146.cif](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/5000146.cif)) and load it with any crystallographic viewer if you prefer to work offline. For beginners I'd recommend [Mercury](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/mercury/), there is a free version available for Windows, macOS and Linux:

[image]

N. B. The asymmetric unit in this structure contains two molecules of picric acids – with and without H-atoms. Obviously, you need the one with the protons assigned.